# Why does this function return true instead of false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my test:

```
var test = function () {
    $.each([1, 2], function () {
        if(true !== false) { // it is just an example
            alert('I am here'); 
            return false; // how should I make the function test to stop or to exit here?
        }
    });
    return true;
}​;

alert(test());
```

​

I would like the `test` function to return false but it returns true.
Why? How should I fix the code? Please see the comments for more details.

Comment: If you have to iterate a set of jQuery objects you can make it easy. You can find the first element that match a given predicate using .filter(...).first()

Answer (score 13):

Returning `false` from the `.each()` callback just halts the `.each()` iteration.  It doesn't return from the enclosing function; the only way to do that in JavaScript is to throw an exception.

What you could do is set a flag:

```
var test = function () {
    var abort = false;
    $.each([1, 2], function () {
        if(true !== false) { // it is just an example
            alert('I am here'); 
            abort = true;
            return false; // how should I make the function test to stop or to exit here?
        }
    });
    return !abort;
}​;
```

Answer (score 4):

It returns `true` because the inner `return false` returns the anonymous function, which only instructs jQuery to end the `$.each` loop early.

Use a variable outside the inner function to properly juggle the return status.

```
var test = function () {
    var retVal = true;
    $.each([1, 2], function () {
        if(true !== false) { // it is just an example
            alert('I am here'); 
            retVal = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return retVal;
}​;
```

You could also change your code to not use the `$.each` method, if a simply `for...in` loop would suffice:

```
var test = function () {
    var retVal = true;
    for (var value in [1, 2]) {
        if(true !== false) { // it is just an example
            alert('I am here'); 
            return false;
        }
    };
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `return false;` just breaks out of the $.each loop.. but not the function.

It returns true from the last statement

Answer (score 1):

fix it by changing your code to:

```
var test = function () {
    var returnValue = true;
    $.each([1, 2], function () {
        if(true !== false) { // it is just an example
            alert('I am here'); 
            returnValue = false;
            return false; // how should I make the function test to stop or to exit here?
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}​;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two function definitions:

- Inner Function (in `$.each`): returns false
- Outer Function (`window.test`): returns true

---

Capture when exited:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var breakpoint = undefined;
$.each(arr, function(i,val){
   if (val==4){  // some break condition
      breakpoint = {index:i,val:val};
      return false;
   }
   return true;
});

console.log('break point:', breakpoint); // breakpoint.index=3, breakpoint.val=4
```

Then in your outer function you can do something like `return typeof breakpoint !== 'undefined';`, or set a `returnValue` as others have suggested.